# Stopping .NET app's SQL Server DB being modifiable via Access using ODBC?

Tags: .net, sql-server, ms-access, odbc

We have a .NET 2.0 winforms app that connects to a SQL Server 2005 database using Windows Authentication. All the database modifications are done using stored procedures which are called from the app. This works fine and users are only permitted to do things that their role permits.

However, it has occurred to us that any user with permission to use the app could theoretically fire up MS Access and connect to the database using ODBC and modify any record they wish on the database.

We have created a Security Group in Active Directory, made this a login in SQL Server and then made this a user in the database with the correct rights to be able to use the app. Other domain users are blocked using db_denydatareader and db_denydatawriter.

How do we go about locking this down so modifications via Access etc. are not possible, whilst the application still functions correctly from the desktop .NET app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL server allows you to assign execute permissions to individual stored procedures.  If all allowed updates are through your stored procedures, add execute permissions to these, and remove data-writer privileges.

Comment: So it's all right to use Access to execute the stored procedures?

Comment: I'd personally use a firewall to block the SQL server from everyone except the approved app server.  But if there's a business need for people with Access to be able to fire-off the stored procedures...